change carrier parameters to disable add APN
I have an application with carrier privileges. I use onLoad to change a configuration, but the configuration does not change on the phone.
the code is:
package com.example.testvolte;
import static android.telephony.CarrierConfigManager.Apn.PROTOCOL_IPV6;
import static android.telephony.CarrierConfigManager.KEY_ALLOW_ADDING_APNS_BOOL;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.service.carrier.CarrierIdentifier;
import android.service.carrier.CarrierService;
import android.telephony.CarrierConfigManager;
import android.telephony.SubscriptionManager;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

public class CarrierConfigService extends CarrierService {
public CarrierConfigService() {
    Log.i("test Volte", "CoIMS - Carrier Config Service created");
}

public final IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.i("test Volte", "CoIMS - Entering onBind");

    return super.onBind(intent);
}

@Override
public final PersistableBundle onLoadConfig(CarrierIdentifier carrierIdentifier) {

    String str;
    Log.i("test Volte", "CoIMS - Carrier Config is being overridden");
    Log.i("test Volte", "CoIMS - CarrierIdentifier id " + carrierIdentifier.toString());

    PersistableBundle configForSubId = ((CarrierConfigManager) getSystemService(Context.CARRIER_CONFIG_SERVICE)).getConfigForSubId(SubscriptionManager.getDefaultSubscriptionId());
    configForSubId = new PersistableBundle();


    configForSubId.putBoolean(KEY_ALLOW_ADDING_APNS_BOOL, false);

    notifyCarrierNetworkChange(true);

    return configForSubId;

}

public final int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int i2, int i3) {
    Log.i("CarrierConfigService", "CoIMS - Starting Carrier Config Service");
    return 3;
}
}

I need to disable adding APN by user.
